# iOS - Enable Private Browsing in WebView

Tags: ios, swift, browser

I want to show private browsing mode like safari with the help of UIWebView. I want to show the same UI as Safari has for private browsing. Screenshot attached.

I have tried to use web view configuration to nonPersistent for websiteDataStore. But it will only help to not store the data.

[image]

Comment: You need to build the UI yourself, this functionality isn't available in UIKit

Answer (score 0):

According to the NSHTTPCookieStorage docs, cookies are not shared
 between applications:

Yes, UIWebView does have the private browsing mode by default. The
 Cookie data is accessible by the App only.

NSHTTPCookie's singleton instance stores the Cookie information of
 the UIWebView. You may need to use deleteCookie: method to clear the
 cached data

I  totally agree with  @Scriptable For UI like Safari you need to
 design as per your requirements